# Unix shell script to check if a file or directory with same name exists

Tags: shell, unix

I want to check if a file or directory with same name exists.
Is there any operator (expect `-e`) to check the file or directory, I dont want to add any extra condition.

Following code works fine to check the existence of a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -e /path/to/the/file/sample ]
then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "nok"
fi
```

Note that `sample` can be a file or a directory.

Answer (score 0):

In my tests with bash 4.2 , the condition `[ -e /path/to/the/file/sample ]` works for **BOTH** files and directories.

As an alternative you can :
Either to use another operator like -d according to [bash man page.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)

```
if [ -e /path/to/the/file/sample ] || [ -d /path/to/the/file/sample ];then echo "ok"; else echo "nok";fi
```

Or to use the exit code of a command like `ls`.

```
if ls "/path/to/the/file/sample" &>/dev/null ; then echo "is here";else echo "not here";fi
```

If you try to perform `ls` on an existed file or directory `ls` will return 0, otherwise will return a non-zero value (returns 2 in my tests for non-existed files or directories).
Quoting is necessary to handle correct names that may  include spaces.

Comment: @Yash Are you sure that `-e` is not working for directories in your case?